# iPhone: make a call

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way for my app to call a certain number and to play a certain sound?

Thanks.

Comment: I certainly hope not. That would be such a malware bait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call a number by requesting the URL `tel://###-###-###`, but this will quit your application and launch the iPhone's default phone application. There is no way of playing a sound as your application has exited at that point.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://91-123******"]];
```