# Will this code work for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582327/how-to-make-a-call-programmatically)

I was wondering if this strip of code will work on iPhone, I can't test it since I only have ipodtouch and simulator.This is all there is to it in code. Also, are there any rules or guidelines that are against this do I need to add a message if it doesn't work? Thanks for any response I may receive.

```
 -(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:2135554321"]];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[iPhone: make a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239328/iphone-make-a-call)

It seems, you must change your code to

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://2135554321"]];
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have to add forward slashes and links?

Comment: You don't need the forward slashes, and probably should not include them as the standard defines `@"tel:2135554321"` as the correct format. However as far as I know it will work with slashes.